# problems with double send/recv

Tags: c, sockets, send, recv

i've a problem with send/recv: if the client send two strings, server receive the two in only one recv and the second recv attend a third send from the client (that i don't want to send). I would like to send 2 strings and receive 2 strings. How can i do?

My code:
CLIENT

```
char login[] = "admin";
char password[] = "admin";

send(sd, login, strlen(login), 0);
send(sd, password, strlen(password), 0);
```

SERVER:

```
bzero(login,MAX);
bzero(password,MAX);

recv(sd_client, login, sizeof(login), 0);
recv(sd_client, password, sizeof(password), 0);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TCP cannot send/recv strings.  TCP cannot send/recv messages longer than one byte.  TCP cannot send/recv structs longer than one byte.

TCP transport is a byte stream.

If you want to transfer anything more complex than one byte, you need an extra protocol on top, hence HTTP, SMTP, etc. etc. protocols.

If you specifically want to send null-terminated strings, for example, you need to buffer and concatenate received data until a null is detected - then you have your 'C'-style string and can proceed to assemble the next string.

Rgds,
Martin

Comment: it's a good idea to use a sleep(1) between the recv and the send?  it works!

Comment: No, it doesn't.  What you are doing is entering a lottery on every exchange.  This is your lucky day/environment:)  If you do some more testing on different links etc, you will lose badly:)  Do not attempt to deliver such a solution - it will not work.  You must assemble your strings properly and correctly in such a manner that it will work no matter wheter 1 of 10000 bytes are taken in each recv() call.  Anything else WILL break :(

Comment: @myself, I think not, because the TCP protocol implements a reliable connection that waits the needed time for the data automatically.

Comment: @JLledo - yes, if the size of the data is known you can just wait for it - that is a protocol definition:)  Typically, usernames/passwords are of varying lengths that cannot be known before login.

Comment: On of the most common mistakes of socket programming is "the size of what you send() is the length of what you recv()". Coalescing and segmentation of messages makes the return value of recv() a very unpredictable value. But if you treat it as such, you can have a very robust protocol implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're using two char arrays for the variables "login" and "password" in your server side.

In this case, for create them, you had to give them a fixed size in its declaration, what is the size of this arrays?, what is the size of the MAX macro?

In your client you're using five-length arrays, if the MAX macro is 10-bytes length of more, then the first recv() will read the both sendings.

Comment: client and server MAX define is 8192, but it doesn't exist a character (like the \0 in strings) that is "STOP" for TCP recv/send?

Comment: @myself I'm afraid not, you must know the size of the data you will send and receive, if the array of the server is 8192 bytes long, then you must send 8192 bytes, the first five must be "admin", the sixth a '\0' and all the rest can be zeros or trash.